# Handling managed Hibernate DAO exceptions in Dropwizard

Tags: java, hibernate, jersey, dropwizard

I'm having a problem with Dropwizard where I can't catch the exception thrown by the Hibernate DAO object within my resource.

I have the following DAO object

```
public class ApplicantDAO extends AbstractDAO<Applicant>
{
    public ApplicantDAO(SessionFactory factory)
    {
        super(factory);
    }

    public long create(Applicant person)
    {
        return persist(person).getApplicantId();
    }
}
```

I am calling the create method from inside my Dropwizard resource to which I'm passing on my managed DAO from my Application's run method. The following doesn't work:

```
try
{
    long id = dao.create(applicant);
    message += "[Stored: " + id + "] ";
}catch (HibernateException ex)
{
    message +="Could't store: " + exptionToString(ex);
}
```

Instead I get Dropwizard's/Jersey's message:

```
{"code":500,"message":"There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID a785167e05024c69)."}
```

Is there a way to get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was happening because of an exception throw inside of a transaction.

So instead of having @UnitOfWork on my resource method, I added @UnitOfWork(transactional = false)

Then I was able to manage my own transactions by passing in the SessionFactory to my resource and that did the trick!

It might be related to the following issue: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/949

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Drop Wizard.

But my best guest is that it has a JAX-RS ExcepionMapper registered that writes its own error when an exception is thrown

see : javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. Is there a way to make the exception fall through to be handled in my code?

Comment: maybe if you register your own mapper,  which handles a very specific exception, of register an exception mapper that has an higher priority

Comment: see @Priority annotation, not sure it works with exception mappers.... worth a try

Comment: other suggestion : you can throw a WebApplicationException, with a non-null response (as they are not caught by exception mappers to my knowledge) ...   something like throw new WebApplicationException(response)

Comment: Thanks. If I put a Try/Catch inside the "create" method, the exception is never caught.

Comment: I tried all of these with no luck. I'm looking for a way to catch an exception as it happens